# Using variable name the same as column name - Clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse, with-statement

I have a table `mytable` and `mydate` is a column in it.
However, since the `SELECT` clause is dynamic, I need to pre-adjust the column with `addMinutes`.
So, the column is added to the variable with the function such that in the event the column turns up in `SELECT` the variable is taken over than the actual value in the table.

`SELECT mydate FROM "mytable"`

> original value of `mydate` is returned

`WITH addMinutes(mydate,300) AS mydate SELECT mydate FROM "mytable"`

> original value of `mydate` is returned, expected to return variable value

The exact opposite happens; Even if the variable is mentioned (same name as the column), the actual column value overrides the `WITH` clause.

Do we have a workaround to use `WITH` clause variables with the same name as the columns in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    * REPLACE addMinutes(mydate, 300) AS mydate, mytable.mydate
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any workaround. The real question is: Why do you need the `WITH` clause to use the same variable name?

Everything works as expected if you use a different name:

```
WITH 
   addMinutes(mydate, 300) AS mynewdate
SELECT 
   mynewdate,
   mydate 
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: I have a scenario where the SELECT clause is dynamic and cannot apply any date functions or use an alternate columns name